# how to make your web page automatically adjust on the size of a web browser?

Tags: html, css

Hello i would like to know what code can be used for an auto adjusting web page like this [site](http://kernix.com) thank you for answering!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I created a small but useful demo for you, using a media query. There are many ways of doing it, however at the core, most ways use these basic functions.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ns3u7uf5/8/

**html**

```
<h1 class="header">YOUR HEADER OR SOMETHING</h1>
<div class="box-1">
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="box-2">
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="box-3">
    <h1>BOX 3</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{text-align: center;}

.box-1, .box-2, .box-3{width: calc(100% / 3); height: 200px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
.box-2{background-color: red;}

/*stuff that will happen below 700px wide*/
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .header{display: none;}
    .box-1, .box-2, .box-3{width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: red; float: left;}
    .box-2{background-color: blue;}
}
```